# RavenDB Object properly saved but some empty attributes when querying

Tags: python, json, ravendb

I'm currently trying to save some python objects (websites) via PyRavenDB  in a RavenDB database. The problem is that data are saved properly, but when I test it by querying the results, some of the attributes are returned empty.
The code is simple, I can't properly find be the problem.

The JSON object in the database is the following (verified via the DB web UI).

```
{
    "htmlCode": "<code>TEST HTML</code>",
    "added": "2017-02-21",
    "uniqueid": "262e4584f3e546afa2c67045a0096b54",
    "url": "www.example.com",
    "myHash": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
    "lastaccessed": "2017-02-21"
}
```

When I use this code to query

```
from pyravendb.store import document_store
        store =  document_store.documentstore(url="http://somewhere:someport", database="websites")
        store.initialize()
        with store.open_session() as session:
            query_result = list(session.query().where_equals("www.example.com", url))
            print query_result
            print type(query_result)
            return query_result
```

It returns this object :

```
{
 'uniqueid': 'f942e86f965d4709a2d69caca3001f2a',
 'url': '',
 'myHash': 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
 'htmlCode': '',
 'added': '2017-02-21',
 'lastaccessed': '2017-02-21'
}
```

As you can see, url and html code are empty. They should be okey since in DB they are properly stored.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the metadata for this document?

Comment: I "solved" it by explicitly calling the arguments like this : where_equals("url", url).select(param1, param2, .....) The metadata is the following:  {
    "Raven-Entity-Name": "Websites",
    "Raven-Python-Type": "__main__.Website"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't use the where_equal right.
where_equal first argument is the field name you want to query with and then the value (`def where_equals(self, field_name, value)`).

Just change this line `query_result = list(session.query().where_equals("www.example.com", url))`

To this `query_result = list(session.query().where_equals("url", "www.example.com"))`

This will fix your problem